# Webpack / jquery.ns-autogrow Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, autogrow

Hy there

I'm new to Webpack or JS-bundel in general. So this question might sound dumb. If so, I'm sorry..

I'm using webpack to bundle all JS files. So far I have this im `main.js`:

```
var jQuery  = require('jquery');
var autogrow = require('jquery.ns-autogrow');

(function($){

    $(function(){
        $('textarea').autogrow();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

But now I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined` right at the beginning of the ns-autogrow plugin/module.

```
(function($, window) {
    return $.fn.autogrow = function(options) { ...
```

Is there something I made wrong requiring the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include jquery dependency at the global scope of your app to use it this way :

```
(function($){

    $(function(){
        $('textarea').autogrow();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

To do it, you should use something like :

```
externals: {
    // require("jquery") is external and available
    //  on the global var jQuery
    "jquery": "jQuery"
}
```

you can see more details at this [address](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html)

I hope it may help

Comment: Thanks! I added `,externals: { "jquery": "jQuery" }` to my webpack gulp task and removed the `var jQuery  = require('jquery');` from my `main.js`. But now it does not even include jQuery anymore.. Any Ideas?

Comment: Now it seems to clear up a bit. If I put it in "external", webpack thinks jQuery will be included outside the webpack bundle, right? But what if I want to include jQuery to the bundle as well?

Comment: You can still use the `var jQuery = require('jquery');` also you can add this statement to your webpack conf in externals : "$" : "jQuery" to allow the use of $ alias .

Comment: This $ alias will allow external libs or package to use this notation to run things like `(function($, window) {
    return $.fn.autogrow = function(options) { ...`

Comment: Sorry. No luck. As soon as I add the `'jquery': 'jQuery'` to the externals, jQuery is not longer inside the bundle. Instead I find `module.exports = jQuery;`